# How to differentiate statements describing state vs action

Tags: nlp, spacy

As a newbie to NLP and spaCy, I would like to be able to determine if a statement describes a state (of being) or an action.

In a simple test of spaCy, I thought that the lemma' property of the verb used would help to indicate this. I tried the following two sentences.

1) I am a netflix subscriber
gave these token results:
I - PRON
am - VERB
a - DET
netflix - NOUN
subscriber - NOUN

and the lemma for the verb 'am' was given as u'be'

2) I navigate to the start page
gave these token results:
I - PRON
navigate - VERB
to - ADP
the - DET
start - NOUN
page - NOUN

and the lemma for the verb 'navigate' was given as u'be'.

So relying on the lemma will not work. What will work for the above examples? And generally?

Thanks in anticipation.

Colin Goldberg

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this (much) later, I tested the second statement again - in isolation.

ie.
Statement: "I navigate to the start page"

```
doc = nlp(u'I navigate to the start page')
for token in doc:
  print('{} - {}'.format(token, token.pos_))
I - PRON
navigate - VERB
to - ADP
the - DET
start - NOUN
page - NOUN

t = doc[1]
t.lemma_
u'navigate'
```

ie. I can now differentiate between these two statements - in terms of my objective - by using the lemma_ function.

So the problem I had before was one where the contents of doc had not been cleared prior to testing the second statement. I should have seen this coming before, but I did not. At the same time the second assignment to doc (ie. doc = nlp(u'I navigate to the start page') ) did not overwrite the previous value - which was not obvious to me.

Thanks for reading this.

Colin Goldberg